# JUnit dependencies not being loaded in

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-boot

I have the following JUnit Test Suite, when I try to load my tests, the dependencies I have autowired in the classes I am testing do not seem to get loaded in, and I get the following error message:

```
package com.uk.jacob.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import com.uk.jacob.model.Ping;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = PingerService.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PingerServiceTests {

    @Test
    public void testPingerServiceReturnsOkWhenServiceIsUp(){
        PingerService pingerService = new PingerService();
        Ping ping = pingerService.ping("http://devnews.today");

        assertEquals(true, ping.ok);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPingerServiceReturnsOkWhenServiceIsDown(){
        PingerService pingerService = new PingerService();
        Ping ping = pingerService.ping("https://jacob.uk.comz");

        assertEquals(false, ping.ok);
    }

}

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.uk.jacob.service.PingerService.setHttpAdapter(com.uk.jacob.adapter.HttpAdapter); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.uk.jacob.adapter.HttpAdapter] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

PingerService:

```
package com.uk.jacob.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.uk.jacob.adapter.HttpAdapter;
import com.uk.jacob.model.Ping;

@Component
public class PingerService {

    HttpAdapter httpAdapter;

    public Ping ping(String urlToPing) {
        Ping ping = new Ping();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = httpAdapter.createHttpURLConnection(urlToPing);

            if(connectionIsOk(connection)){
                ping.ok = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ping.ok = false;
        }

        return ping;
    }

    private boolean connectionIsOk(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        return connection.getResponseCode() == 200;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setHttpAdapter(HttpAdapter httpAdapter){
        this.httpAdapter = httpAdapter;
    }

}
```

HttpAdapter:

```
package com.uk.jacob.adapter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class HttpAdapter {
    public HttpURLConnection createHttpURLConnection(String urlToPing) throws IOException{
        URL url = new URL(urlToPing);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the @Autowired from the setter and set it on the attribute?

Comment: And don't create in each Test a new PingService(). The creation of object handles Spring for you. Inject a PingService in the Test class with @Autowired and use this.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your pingerService like

PingerService pingerService = new PingerService();

in the testclass, so its not a spring bean, so spring will not inject nothing there, it wont work.
Instead add the PingerService to your spring configuration :
Annotate it with @Component and put it somewhere where it can be found in the classpath or create it with a @Bean annotated method in a your spring configuration class.

This leads to the second problem :

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = PingerService.class)
```

You have to provide here a configuration class, and not a single service.
The configuration class must instantiate the spring beans, in your case at least PingerService and HttpAdapter.

Have a look at [Spring java config (older version)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/)

**regarding your comment : For the config class, would an annotated @SpringBootApplication class be sufficient?**

Yes that would be sufficient, if the PingerService and HttpAdapter are located in subpackages of that SpringBootApplication annotated class, so they can be found by the ComponentScan.

A ComponentScan is configured automatically  if you use @SpringBootApplication

Comment: For the config class, would an annotated @SpringBootApplication class be sufficient? Which calls SpringApplication.run(SimplePingApplication.class, args);